# Does Inserting, Updating, Deleting and Querying in Android Room Persistence ever fails?

Tags: java, android

I am just curious about it.. I just recently used room and would like to know more about it.. does querying ever fails? I am using AsyncTask when inserting or querying by the way.. and I don't have any callback.. i just execute it and then it's save.. and whenever I am querying, I do it like this:

```
try {
    List<Object> objectList = new GetObjectTask.execute().get();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStack();
}
```

is this the proper way?

and this is GetObjectTask class

```
public class GetObjectTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Object>> {

    public GetObjectTask() {
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Object> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        return AppDatabaseHelper.getInstance().getObjectDao().getAllObject();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this the proper way?

It depends on your design.

- Implementing in this would require you to implement the lifecycle aware data update your-self. This in turn will result in adding boilerplate code to manage the configuration changes. Also you need to add extra code to parse the list and update views accordingly
- You Activity will be bloated with the code for accessing the data from DB. Ideally you should avoid this and make Activity only responsible for dealing with view data. Activity shouldn't have concern about source of data.

**Proper way would be:**

- Implement a [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) architecture component and let ViewModel handle the db operations.
- Since Room is capable of returning the `LiveData`, you can easily observe the changes and update your views accordingly. Check out the [observable queries](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#query-observable) for this purpose

Comment: Yes.. I am performing the operation in background.. this is my code inside my asynctask.

 @Override
    protected List<RetroBeacon> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        return AppDatabaseHelper.getInstance().getBeaconsDao().getAllBeacons();
    }

Comment: @ChristianBringino Update your question with this information.

Comment: Done.. i Updated my question

Comment: @ChristianBringino check the udpated answer

Comment: Thanks! But you still haven't answered my question though...does querying or inserting ever fail, sir?

Comment: @ChristianBringino It can fail if you didn't set up the constraints properly. E.g. You are trying to insert same data again and didn't set the conflict policy. There could be some IOException in case you decided to write your own handler for custom query.